# iPhone app, navigationcontroller not functioning?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar

I have 4 tabs in a tab bar. In one of the tabs i want to use a navigation, i.e. when i click an item from the list it should go to some details page about it. I have the list page where i have the navigation bar and the list of items. I  can scroll them, but when I click any of them the selection animation happens, console logs the true row value, it even prints log instructions from constructor of the Details page but I can not see the Details page showing up. (btw Xcode 3.2.6 with iOS 4.3)

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
        NSString *rowValue = [myStrings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(rowValue);
        //[Utility setStr:rowValue];
        [self.myTable deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:TRUE];

            //DETAILS PAGE HERE!!!!
        RestViewController * rest= [[RestViewController alloc] init];
        rest.scoreLabel.text = rowValue;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:rest animated:TRUE];
        [rest release];
 }
```

Anybody having any idea? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: First, after `RestViewController * rest= [[RestViewController alloc] init];`, put `NSLog(@"rest = %@", rest);`, to make sure it is not only constructed but returned.  Also, if `RestViewController` is well behaved, it will not have constructed `scoreLabel` at this point, but will only do so when `loadView` is called during `pushViewController`.  Have you read the "Subclassing Notes" in the [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `pushViewController:` if your view controller stack is being managed by a UINavigationController.  If the viewController you are trying to push onto is not being managed by a Navigation Controller, nothing will happen.

It sounds like this is the case if your app.  Be sure your View Controller hierarchy is set up this way:

1. You have a `UITabBarController` at the top level.
2. The tab you are working with should manage a `UINavigationController`
3. Your tableViewController should be set as the `rootViewController` of the navigation controller in #2

Comment: yea ur right. I added another class with a navigationcontroller to the tab. The navigates between two views now.
THANKS!!!